# "AllAccessDisabled: All access to this object has been disabled" error being thrown when copying between S3 Buckets

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am getting this error:

```
AllAccessDisabled: All access to this object has been disabled
```

When performing the `s3.copyObject` function in my node Lambda function.

Is this error being thrown because of insufficient permissions on the source bucket, or because of insufficient permissions on the target bucket?

Answer (score 25):

This error means you are trying to access a bucket that has been locked down by AWS so that nobody can access it, regardless of permissions -- *all access* has been disabled.

It can occur because a bill goes unpaid and probably for other reasons as well...

**However**... *usually* this means you've made a mistake in your code and are not accessing the bucket that you think you are.

[`s3.copyObject`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property) expects `CopySource` to be this:

```
'/' + source_bucket_name + '/' + object_key
```

If you overlook this and supply something like `/uploads/funny/cat.png` you're going to get exactly this error, because here, `uploads` is the bucket name and `funny/cat.png` is the object key... and [the bucket named `uploads`](https://uploads.s3.amazonaws.com) happens to be a bucket that returns the `AllAccessDisabled` error... so the real error here is that you are accessing the wrong bucket.

Comment: Note that the bucket named `uploads` -- whoever that bucket belongs to -- no longer returns the `AllAccessDisabled` error like it did back when this answer was written.

Answer (score 4):

If your bucket name does Not match with bucket name in your code, it will also throw an error 403 forbidden. Make sure you spell correctly

Answer (score 0):

Adding to that above points, check the subscription status.