# Secure AWS S3 file url how to display in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3

This is my url:

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/balamurugan/s3fs-private/account/001.jpg

While i'm hitting this url i'm getting **below error**:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>25009395C98B106D</RequestId>
<HostId>
NCNCMP6Bx5P95M/x3rENmpE0cwlQ3wtcsO5q71YSJlQCy4p/Ulk1+k0x8nYr1i+DhQRmKbMuFoA=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["AllAccessDisabled: All access to this object has been disabled" error being thrown when copying between S3 Buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329023/allaccessdisabled-all-access-to-this-object-has-been-disabled-error-being-thr)

Comment: Your bucket content is marked as private. You need to either make it public or mount the bucket in your server and access the files as local routes `/home/your_user/bucket_mount_directory/file_name.jpg`