# Error with PutBucketWebsite command in python sdk

Tags: python, web, amazon-s3, sdk

I am creating static website in S3 bucket via python sdk using the code shown below

```
website_configuration = {
     'ErrorDocument': {'Key': 'error.html'},
     'IndexDocument': {'Suffix': 'index.html'}
       }
s3_client.put_bucket_website(Bucket='bucket_name', 
            WebsiteConfiguration=website_configuration
               )
```

Have also tried explicitly stating WebsiteConfiguration in the method argument. 
I get the following error (with traceback)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/aws-modern-application-workshop/sdk_code.py", line 107, in <module>
    WebsiteConfiguration=website_configuration
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AllAccessDisabled) when calling the PutBucketWebsite operation: All access to this object has been disabled
```

Appears to be an issue with permissions, however the same program (code not shown) was used to create the bucket, set bucket policy and upload index.html & error.html files. In addition, I am able to create the static website via AWS CLI command within the same IDE session (using Cloud9). The IAM user associated with the Cloud9 session has ADMIN permission and I've checked the config and credential files to ensure they contain region and user keys, respectively.
I need suggestions for how to resolve this error.

Comment: [amazon s3 - "AllAccessDisabled: All access to this object has been disabled" error being thrown when copying between S3 Buckets - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53330614/174777) suggests that the bucket is not yours. Are you sure you have the correct bucket name? I ran your code on my own bucket and it worked fine, but when I used a bucket name of `bucket_name`, I got the AllAccessDisabled error message.

Comment: Thanks. Your comment helped me focus my efforts to fix the problem.