# IAM user unable to DeleteObject

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

After creating an IAM user, I am not able to perform a DeleteObject action. Necessary info (Access key ID, Secret access key etc.) have been inserted as env variables. Upload, Downlaod operations can be performed without issue.

IAM user policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::************"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::************",
                "arn:aws:s3:::************/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

##### Bucket Permissions

Block all public access: off (all 4 options)

##### Error Message

Performing s3.Object('BUCKET_NAME','fol.jpeg').delete()

gets me this error message:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AllAccessDisabled) when calling the DeleteObject operation: All access to this object has been disabled

Comment: Suspended AWS account would cause this. Are you able to download objects from that same bucket now? 100% sure you have the bucket name correct? Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329023/allaccessdisabled-all-access-to-this-object-has-been-disabled-error-being-thr).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Suspended account is not my case, since other operations can be performed without an issue.

Comment: Double check the bucket name. The point here is that if you have accidentally supplied the wrong bucket name, it could be for an existing bucket in a suspended account, and would cause this error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Eventually, it is a case of suspended account. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical reason that you would see `AllAccessDisabled` is that AWS has suspended the underlying account. If that turns out not to be the cause, then read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329023/allaccessdisabled-all-access-to-this-object-has-been-disabled-error-being-thr) for other possibilities.

Also, information on reactivating a suspended account is [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reactivate-suspended-account/).

Comment: Specifically, my credentials have been compromised, so AWS automatically applied "AWSCompromisedKeyQuarantineV2" policy on that specific user.