# An error occurred (AllAccessDisabled) when calling the PutObject operation: All access to this object has been disabled

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

[image]I have changed my bucket policy as well as given the I am user s3 permission also and still getting the same error. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Did the bucket policy change trigger this error? Or has your AWS account been suspended? Or are you trying to copy an object but have mis-specified the bucket name? Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329023/allaccessdisabled-all-access-to-this-object-has-been-disabled-error-being-thr).

Comment: before adding the bucket policy the error was still the same, So what happened is i have shifted my ec2 instance to another aws account, I have changed the bucket name with the new bucket name in my code and as well as change the aws access and secret key too, I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: Please be sure to read the linked question. Is it relevant?

Comment: Yeah, i did try checking all these factors and other available answers too, but no help