# Amazon S3 Url Bucket Shortener

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I am making a link shortener on amazon.
I want to shorten it like bit.ly but there is a problem.
How do I run the link with redirect. It didn't work with PHP.
I'm getting this error, I couldn't solve the problem.
My idea is to just create and redirect links like this.

https://s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/gitci/git.php

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AllAccessDisabled</Code>
<Message>All access to this object has been disabled</Message>
<RequestId>XCWQMDPEKRPR10V7</RequestId>
<HostId>nhYKlMUJx4nhjbUo3s+hk/sKLYK78NJWf/RddJ9GjLpUl+XjCw3O7aoUJIcK/0+0RS2Bf0V+tt4=</HostId>
</Error>
```

i am try this code

```
<?php header("Location: https://www.muslu.net"); ?>
```

Comment: Does the linked Q&A answers your question? For the error message itself please see as well ["AllAccessDisabled: All access to this object has been disabled" error being thrown when copying between S3 Buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53329023/367456) and [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions-on-stack-overflow/255746#255746).